# How to solve the problem of GEE computation time out?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

The overall code is the same. At first, I used more than 1,000 sample points to classify the land in study area A. At this time, the code was completely normal; then I replaced more than 1,000 sample points with more than 10,000 sample points, and changed study area A into study area B. The code The result cannot appear, and it displays: computation time out!

I expect to be able to solve the calculation timeout problem of GEE.